# Is it possible to set MPNowPlayingInfoCenter to show some info like title and artist label without actually playing any AVPlayer or Content?

Tags: uikit, avplayer, avaudiosession, mpnowplayinginfocenter

Previously i already developed some feature regarding showing some info of notification player in iOS which is to displayed what music or content that you're listen to using AVPlayer with the help of MPNowPlayingInfoCenter. But i'm curious, can you set some information of the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter without actually playing the content from AVPlayer.

Because from my experience, yes you have to set the info for the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter first and then only after the AVPlayer started playing, the notification with the info that already set is showed.

So the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter only gonna show once there's some content is played. Are those cannot be separated? For my need right now, i want to record and also showing what is the title for the recording.